# PHP Illegal string offset in foreach loops (Facebook app)

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, offset

I am new to PHP and i am trying to make here a very simple facebook app that displays a random number of friends' profile pictures ( 9 friends ). It does display what i want EXCEPT for an orange error sign saying "(!)Warning: Illegal string offset in 'id'..."

This is my code by the way:  (i have already called the facebook sdk and defined $contacts)

```
<?php
if(isset($contacts)){ 
$i = 1;

echo '<table>';
foreach ($contacts as $friends) {
shuffle($friends);
    foreach ($friends as $value)  {

    echo '<td>';
    echo '<img src ="https://graph.facebook.com/' . $value["id"] . '/picture/>';
    echo '</td>';

    if ($i >= 9) {
        break;
    }                           
    $i = $i + 1;

}}                         
echo '</table>';


} 


?>
```

Thank you very much. I appreciate any tip or clue. =D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just means your "id" key doesn't always exist for each loop.
Add :

```
if(isset($value['id'])){
   .
   .
   .
}
```

just after `foreach ($friends as $value)  {`

Comment: Ah, I see! Thank you very much Julien, it fixed it! ^_^